# SQL query to show details of bookings that will be staying in a hotel on a specific night using only check in and check out dates

Tags: mysql, sql

Apologies if this is a stupid question, but I've scoured the net for answers and have found none. I'm also a student only learning to use SQL for a database class, so this is rather new to me.

I'm doing an assignment which is based on a hotel database and must display the details of bookings that will be staying in the hotel on a specific night.

The bookings table has the following columns:

```
booking_no  guest_no  room_no  date_in  date_out
```

The dates are formatted as (yyyy-mm-dd).

The question is roughly as follows:

"Write a query to display details of the bookings that will be staying in the hotel on the night of 18th March, 2018. This includes bookings that are checking in on the 18th of March and also bookings that checked in before this date but will not check out until after the 18th."

I have tried the following query:

```
select *

from bookings

where date_in <='2018-03-18' and date_out >='2018-03-18'
```

but since there are two conditions both being satisfied exclusively, it does not work.

I need a query which shows rows which only satisfy both of these conditions and not just one or the other.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: look out this link(https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to know more on how to improve the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the query below with give you details of bookings  in the `WHERE` clause I've filtered the results for bookings arriving before 18th March 2018 and leaving after 18th March 2018

```
SELECT 
Booking_no,
Guest_no,
Room_no
FROM bookings
WHERE date_in < '2018-03-18'
AND (date_out >'2018-03-18' OR date_out IS NULL)
```

Comment: I've tried this but it shows rows that satisfy only one condition and not both of them.

Comment: @Alphano I've added the case for when the date_out IS NULL, let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
Booking_no,
Guest_no,
Room_no
FROM bookings
WHERE '2018-03-18' between date_in AND date_out
```

Answer (score 0):

Select * from bookings where date_in <= '18-Mar-2018' and date_out is null.

My assumptions are as below.

1. Convert dates between Varchar and Date by using TO_CHAR and TO_DATE functions 
   as per your need.
2. date_out is null for bookings which still stays in hotel.

Please comment if you need anything else.